# Wildfly 21 - run application client

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I was previously on JBoss EAP 5 and runned an application client with the following command line :

> export RUNCLIENT_CLASSPATH="$RUNCLIENT_CLASSPATH:$JBOSS_HOME/client/jbossall-client.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/client/jboss-metadata.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/lib/jboss-classloader.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/lib/jboss-classloading-spi.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/lib/jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/lib/jboss-classloading.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/lib/jboss-dependency.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/lib/jboss-reflect.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/lib/jboss-kernel.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/lib/jboss-xml-binding.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/lib/jboss-vfs.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/common/lib/jboss-ejb3-core.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/common/lib/antlr.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/common/lib/commons-collections.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/common/lib/commons-logging.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/common/lib/hibernate-core.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/common/lib/quartz.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/lib/postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc3.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/lib/dom4j.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/lib/jaxrpc.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/lib/saaj.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/lib/commons-discovery-0.2.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/lib/axis.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/lib/wsdl4j.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/client/activation.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/client/mail.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/common/lib/c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/common/lib/poi.jar"
>
> $JAVA_HOME/bin/java  -Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory   -Xmx1024m -classpath $RUNCLIENT_CLASSPATH org.jboss.client.AppClientMain -jbossclient Main batch MYBEAUTIFULBATCH -launchers org.jboss.ejb3.client.ClientLauncher -j2ee.clientName MYPROJECT_BATCH

I've upgrade to wildfly 21 but i can't find how to do the same ?

I tried the following :

> C:/WildFly/wildfly-21.0.2.Final/bin/appclient.sh C:/WildFly/wildfly-21.0.2.Final/standalone/deployments/MYPROJECT.ear#MYPROJECT_BATCH-1.0.jar batch MYBEAUTIFULBATCH

But i get the error :

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.jboss.modules.Main

How can i do on Wildfly what i did on JBoss 5 ?

Comment: You are converting from an application server that stopped support 5 years ago.  You need to figure out where each of these files are now (if they still exist).  It looks like you're running an EJB client of some sort - do you know if your client code still works?  Wildfly does have `org.jboss.as.server.Main` but I'm not positive that it works the same as your old server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, i'm on windows, i've to use .bat instead of .sh

So like this :

> C:/WildFly/wildfly-21.0.2.Final/bin/appclient.bat C:/WildFly/wildfly-21.0.2.Final/standalone/deployments/MYPROJECT.ear#MYPROJECT_BATCH-1.0.jar batch MYBEAUTIFULBATCH